# Forcing all outgoing connections through proxies

Tags: linux, proxy, http, socks-proxy

How can I do this in Linux? It'd be nice if there was a way to transparently force connections through proxies rather than configure them individually for each program.

Answer (score 5):

You want [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/).  From the Ubuntu package manager description:

> Proxy chains force any tcp connection made by any given tcp client
>   to follow through proxy (or proxy chain). It is a kind of proxifier.
>   It acts like sockscap / premeo / eborder driver ( intercepts TCP calls )
>
> This version supports SOCKS4, SOCKS5 and HTTP CONNECT proxy servers.
>   Different proxy types can be mixed in the same chain.
>
> Features:
>
> - Access Internet from behind restrictive firewall.
> - Source IP masquerade.
> - SSH tunneling and forwarding.
> - Dynamic LAN-to-LAN VPN channel.
> - Servers and daemons friendly (works fine with sendmail MTA).

Comment: note that simply setting the http_proxy environment variable will tell many http-using programs that you _want_ them to use this proxy.  It just won't force them if they don't refer to the variable or have their own settings.  It's a simple setting which works for many cases.

Comment: Hey, looks exactly like what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ScoBe sadly, many is nowhere near enough. Using the Heroku toolbelt, for example, and wget seems to choke on my proxy settings (because I have username/password, and it thinks the username is a hostname). But thank you for this answer, it's exactly what I needed.