# force applications to use proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force programs that do not specify proxy settings to use a proxy (ie: Steam)](https://superuser.com/questions/18417/force-programs-that-do-not-specify-proxy-settings-to-use-a-proxy-ie-steam)
>   [Forcing all outgoing connections through proxies](https://superuser.com/questions/58261/forcing-all-outgoing-connections-through-proxies)

I'm studying in the college and I have a problem with my programs that don't support proxy(with user authentication);

My college server uses squid as it's proxy applications and you need to insert proxy's address, port, user and password in order to use the internet. With browsers, that's OK.(because all most all of them have such settings to be inserted.) but with other applications that lack such settings what should I do to provide them with the internet???

I used Proxifier for tunneling but Proxifier as far as I know doesn't support http proxy (because squid is a http proxy) and it says that ssl disabled in squid configurations in the server (and I cant enable that because of limitations.)

Any way to give internet access to that applications???

Comment: Please specify OS required for which you need PROXY ?

Comment: For the record, [Proxifier does allow HTTP proxies](http://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/http-proxy.htm) with the caveat that you can only use them with HTTP connections. This is more a limitation of the proxy, not Proxifier...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, I can recommend ProxyCap. This application can force other applications to use a specific proxy (which they natively don't support), like a socks/http proxy.

If you are looking for tunneling, you might check out [PingBuster](http://pingbuster.net) and their howto's, which include VPN but also Proxifier/ProxyCap.

Answer (score 0):

If your applications does not have proxy settings and your only way to access Internet is via your network proxy server, you can need to redirect outgoing HTTP traffic to the proxy server. This can be done simply using iptables (if you are on a Linux machine).

However, the network proxy may not have transparent proxying enabled. Also, you still have the authentication issue. To workaround these two points, you can run your own squid proxy and configure the network proxy as parent of your local squid. The local squid can be configured to allow transparent proxying and to pass your credentials to the parent proxy.